# mock variables in a try with resource block to throw IOException using mockito

Tags: junit, mockito

I am trying to write a test case to throw IO exception but couldn't able to mock variables in a try with resources block.

```
private byte[] convertDataToCSV() {

     try (ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream());
                        CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(writer, CSVFormat.DEFAULT
                              .withHeader(CSVHeaders.class))) {
                            
                           printer.printRecord();
                           writer.flush();
                           byte[] bytes = outputStream.toByteArray();
                           return bytes;
            
            }catch(IOException e){
                       //catch exception
            }
}
```

Here I am looking to mock OutputStreamWriter or CSVPrinter so that I can throw IOException when it calls either printRecord() or flush()method. But seems like it's not using the mock.

```
OutputStreamWriter writer = mock(OutputStreamWriter.class)
CSVPrinter printer = mock(CSVPrinter.class)

doThrow(new IOException()).when(printer).printRecord() //didn't work
doThrow(new IOException()).when(writer).flush()//didn't work
```

Is there any way  to use mock variables instead of using it's own objects in try with resources block using mockito?

Comment: Could you please add your whole method here?

Comment: @SSK I have added whole method

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to try something below based on your method signature

```
Mockito.when(myService.getWritter(Mockito.any()))
                .thenThrow(new IOException());
```

replace `myService` with your service mock bean and `getWritter` with your actual method

Answer (score 0):

Local scope variables like `new OutputStreamWriter(new ByteArrayOutputStream())` cannot be easily mocked with mockito.

You can do this with [PowerMockickto](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito), but PowerMockito still does not have support for  JUnit5.

```
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.whenNew;

 // ...
OutputStreamWriter writter = mock(OutputStreamWriter .class);
doThrow(new IOException()).when(printer).printRecord();
whenNew(OutputStreamWriter.class).withArguments(any()).thenReturn(writter);
```

So either you write the test with PowerMockito and JUnit4 or refactor your code with some kind of factory for the StreamWritter and mock that factory method.